# R shiny: create variable in eventReactive that is used inside the defined function

Tags: r, shiny, reactive, treemap

I want to create a shny app that creates a interactive treemap.
The treemap should contain up to three layers, depending on user's choice.
The user can specify one, two or three layers, choosing from a dropdown list for each layer.

Hitting an actioButton, the map should be produced.

The ui part

```
    ui <- fluidPage(
      
      # Application title
      navbarPage("Ist-Analyse Biodiversitätsmonitoring in Deutschland",
                 #####      
                 tabPanel("Treemap", fluid = T,
                          sidebarLayout(
                            sidebarPanel(
                              radioButtons(inputId = "status",
                                           label = "Programm - Status",
                                           choices = c("Alle" = "Alle",
                                                       "laufend" = "laufend",
                                                       "in Erprobung" = "in Erprobung",
                                                       "in Entwicklung" = "in Entwicklung",
                                                       "beendet" = "beendet"),
                                           selected = c("Alle") 
                              ),
                              br(),
                              selectInput(inputId = "level1",
                                          label = "Ebene 1",
                                          choices = Auswahl$Titel[Auswahl$use_treemaps == 1],
                                          selected = Auswahl$Titel[Auswahl$use_treemaps == 1][1]),
                              br(),
                              selectInput(inputId = "level2",
                                          label = "Ebene 2",
                                          choices = Auswahl$Titel[Auswahl$use_treemaps == 1],
                                          selected = c(''),
                              br(),
                              selectInput(inputId = "level3",
                                          label = "Ebene 3",
                                          choices = c('',
                                                      Auswahl$Titel[Auswahl$use_treemaps == 1]),
                                          selected = c('')),
                              
                               actionButton(inputId = "submit", 
                                           label = "Los!",
                                           icon = icon("table")
                              )
                            ),
                            mainPanel(
                              d3tree3Output(outputId = "treemap",
                                            width = "100%",
                                            height = "400px"),
                              )
                          )
                          
                 )
      )
)
```

The server part

```
    server <- function(input, output) {
  
  ### determine, how many levels to drill down
  ## therefore, I bind together the selected levels (1 to 4) in tab "Treemap"
  
  
  
  treemap_reactive <- eventReactive(input$submit, {
    #####
    
    drill_levels<- c(input$level1,
                     input$level2,
                     input$level3)
  
    ## then, depending on lenght(drill_levels), the treemaps
    ## are composed to the defined level of depth
    drill_levels<- drill_levels[-c(which(drill_levels=''))]
    
    treemap<-treemap(groups.1,
                     index=drill_levels,
                     vSize="value",
                     type="index",
                     na.rm=T,
                     draw=F)
    
      d3tree3(treemap,
              rootname = c("Treemap")
      )
    
  }
  )
  
  output$treemap <- renderD3tree3({
    treemap_reactive()
    }
  )
}
    
    # Run the application 
    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The group.1 datatset is the dataset containing the information to be visualized.

If I start the app, choose my levels (either one, two or tree) and hit the actionButton
I get an error "can't find object 'drill_levels'"
However, if I run the code with pre-defining 'drill_levels' in the R global envronment, the code works exactly as I expected.

So the problem seems to be that the variable 'drill_levels' is not created inside the eventReactive() function.

Does someone have an idea how to solve the issue?

Comment: In my opinion Shiny tries to evalute `output$treemap` before inputs are created. Try putting `req(input$level1)`, `req(input$level2)` and `req(input$level3)` before creating `drill_levels` object.

Comment: change `which(drill_levels='')` to `which(drill_levels=='')`

Comment: Your likelihood of getting support increases greatly if you can provide a minimal reproducible example. i.e. declare libraries used; share all required data (enough to be a working example) ; reduce your code as much as possible (likely your issue is not caused by involving 3 levels; does your problem exist in principle with a single level? so ask for help with that first maybe) . good luck to you.